# HTML5: what to do when the page header is equal to the article header?

Tags: html, header, semantics, outline

This has been bugging me for a while now, since the introduction of HTML5:

In some of our designs the page header is actually the title of the article you're viewing, which leads to a missing header in the outline (since the h1 is within the article, not directly a child of the body).

What would be a good practice for countering this?

I'm not a big fan of simply dumping in a hidden h1 in the body, as it's not the best idea for page-ranking for example.

I know that ideally the design would take these kind of things into account, but sometimes (as a developer) it's not your choice to make.

Example mark-up: http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/DuKok

Comment: an example is needed haha

Comment: Here you go, it's a really quick example, but it'll do: http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/DuKok

Comment: Ok, I can see your point better now. Could you also illustrate what outline you would like to achieve? You can use [these](https://gist.github.com/jrvidal/7344342) as a starting point.

Comment: The third outline you have would be the best match in this case, at least that makes the most sense. The second one is certainly out (it misses a heading). The first one is undesirable, but at least it has a valid outline.

Answer (score 4):

From the [HTML draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-article-element):

> When the main content of the page (i.e. excluding footers, headers, navigation blocks, and sidebars) is all one single self-contained composition, the content should be marked up with a **main** element and the content may also be marked with an **article**, but it is technically redundant in this case (since it's self-evident that the page is a single composition, as it is a single document).

According to this, you should drop the `article` container and go only with `main`.

**Update** (8-Nov-2013)

Well, I understand that having untitled sections is unappealing, but for the time being (HTML master draft, November 2013) there is no escape: `<body>` elements are *sectioning roots* that always start a section and are displayed in the outline. An outline such as:

```
The main article title
  └── Related articles
Latest News
Latest Blog Posts
```

is simply not possible with the current outline algorithm in an HTML5 compliant way (you would need to add siblings to the `<body>`).

Since you were considering a suggestion to the W3C, here is an idea: perhaps the outline of a document should default to `<title>`.

Comment: This makes sense up to a certain point. It becomes complicated when you have aside elements that relate to the main content and aside elements that relate to the page in general.

For example: body > aside | main > aside and | article > aside all bear a different relationship. Although I'm not sure about the implied relationship between main and aside, it still poses a practical problem.

Comment: To clarify: dropping all articles and sections for a main element might be a solution in a very simple document structure, but in a typical website with lots of related content in sidebars I don't see this as being a good solution. I don't like the implied sectioning in HTML5, it forces things that might not "be there" in some cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concerns. Could you add to the question a few explicit examples of page structure you'd want to discuss?

Comment: I've updated the Codepen link to reflect what I'm talking about. This is a very basic set-up, but a valid use-cases.

Basically it's a page that needs a title (the issue), it has related content (the asides "Latest News" and "Latest Blog Posts"). Then it shows one article (which ideally is our page title, but the implied section of article prevents that), which also has related content (the aside "Related articles").

Since the "main" element isn't sectioning content, you'd end up with all of the asides bearing the same "weight", which is not correct (they don't all relate to the main content)